# How to make edit text error position in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an app in which I have edit text fields in which I have to enter a mobile number and password. The problem is that the `EditText` error indicator covers the mobile number and password filed, and the user will not be able to enter mobile number. How do I solve this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: show your layout file and what the interface should be

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`.
which can show the error below to the `Edittext`.so You can easily write next thing like your `number` and `password` in the new `Edittext`.

**Here is xml code :**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="60dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="@string/hint_name" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="@string/hint_email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="@string/hint_password" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Let's see the ScreenShot for understand.

Empty **Edittext**.

[image]

Error message **Edittext**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Nitin: Actually Edittext behaviour wants you to focus in the edittext to discard the seterror message to rectify the erroneous data and go to other fields.

Comment: @nitin: Solution ironman suggested is good. And it also includes the material design components which is far superior.