# how to change the background color of the setError() in android

Tags: android

How can I change the background of the setError() method which I am using to display any error occurred in textview. I can change my font color but not the background color.

[image]

My java file:

public class Testing extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText name,email,pass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_name);
    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_email);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_password);

    name.setError("Your name should not contain empty space");
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Use this `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`.
which can show the error below to the `Edittext`.so You can easily write next thing like your `number` and `password` in the new `Edittext`.

**Here is xml code :**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="60dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="@string/hint_name" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="@string/hint_email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="@string/hint_password" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Let's see the ScreenShot for understand.

Empty **Edittext**.

[image]

Error message **Edittext**.

[image]

**For More detail see my Answer :** [How to make edit text error position in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674098/how-to-make-edit-text-error-position-in-android/37674318#37674318)

Comment: Thank you a very good suggestion.. But i want to know whether we could able to change the background of the setError() ? I have went through my sites but i cant get anything clearly..

Comment: @Rishu this is latest library `EditText` and also it is material design to make layout clean and display in very well form. So remove your code and add it.

Comment: yes i tried by using TextInputLayout am stuck with the same problem.. Am not getting the error below like yours..

Comment: am not clear on your ouput.. you have an edittext below that you have another textview to show error ?

Comment: @Rishu no it is only `EditText`.

Comment: i have copied your xml to my project.. can you please say where you set your error message "Enter your full name"?

Comment: @Rishu now what code you use previous use that. `editText.setError("Message");`.

Comment: i have posted my code please take a look at it.. i have tried and getting the same output..